# AdMob match rate stays low, though the policy warning was removed 1+ month ago

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I got the "Ad serving is currently limited" warning after falsely installed the app on my own device (regarded as invalid traffic), shortly after it was published on Google Play.

After reporting the reasons to AdMob, they kindly removed the policy warning.

However, though the warning was removed more than 1 month ago, the AdMob match rate stays low (~4%).

Before the warning, though this is my first app published on Google Play, and though the number of installment was just about 100, the match rate was ~90%.

I haven't updated the app during this period, so the drop in match rate is not likely caused by the ad implementation.

It seems that there might be some kind of "tag" for developer(app) that has ever got a warning, and the "tag" keeps the match rate low.

How can I (get the "tag" removed to) improve the match rate on AdMob?

Have a nice day  :)

Comment: is there any update on your situation regarding match rate?

Comment: It returned to an acceptable level of match rate (> 80%) 2.5 months after the warning.

Comment: I am glad to hear that

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can not remove the "tag" unless Google remove it.

What you can do to enhance your odds:

1. [Set up app-ads.txt for your apps](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en)
2. NEVER click on your ads ever again, and tell your family and friends not to do that
3. Wait and you will see a difference
4. Try to always update admob SDK

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I've previously done all of them, and hope for the best.

Comment: It takes time, be patient